# Build and Publish Docker Image to Prod Env using Asp.Net Core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm a little confused about how I have to build the image for an Asp.Net Core project for a production environment because it should use `aspnetcore` image instead of `aspnetcore-build`, somebody can explain me how is the best way to build and push an image for a production environment, please?

I built the solution in `release` mode, but I'm not sure if VS created the image using `aspnetcore` image, since when I published Docker said that it was mounting the image from `aspnetcore-build` image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured this out. Visual Studio uses a Docker Multi-Stage build when it creates the Docker file, so when it builds the Docker image, in the end, it's using the `aspnetcore` image, which is the last stage build declared on the Docker file, and it uses the `base` stage, which is actually the`aspnetcore` image. This is an example:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.5 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.5-2.1.4 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
WORKDIR /src/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.API.dll"]
```

So, the recommended way to build and publish the Docker image is from our CI/CD process and not manually.